# Label and Image not hovering with border-radius and border

Tags: css

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4XTj/)

Html

```
<label for="home" class="prof">
<img src="http://bigbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/modern-house.jpg" class="image-label" />
</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="home" id="home">
<label for="home" class="type">House Owner</label>
```

CSS

```
.image-label{
  width: 168px;
  height: 168px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}

input[type=radio] + .prof img:hover {
    border: 15px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .prof img {
    border: 15px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .prof img:hover {
    border: 15px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Trying to have border-radius with border color appear when hover the image or after click and tick appear. border-radius with border color seems not to be possible for image? Because I have tried label with background image on local and it worked. However using background image on label caused the tick to be mispositioned despite of absolute positioning.

Help appreciated.

Comment: The last block of properties is useless, because it got the same properties as when input is radio and image is hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<input>` before its siblings `<label>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4XTj/1/

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="home" id="home">  

<label for="home" class="prof">
  <img src="http://bigbackground.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/modern-house.jpg" class="image-label" />
</label>

<label for="home" class="type">House Owner</label>
```

---

FYI, the `+` selector selects the sibling elements after it.

```
input[type=radio] + .prof
```

This selects sibling elements that have `class="prof"` and are after(not before) the `<input tpe="radio">`

---

> It's too bad that there is no standard specification in CSS3 for
>   selecting all sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

label img{border:2px solid #fff;}

label img:hover {border:2px solid #333;}